# Java sort throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, exception

The following lines:

```
ArrayList<ShowdownSingleValueVO> sortedValues = new ArrayList<>();
(...fill the array...)
Collections.sort(sortedValues);
```

Return the following exception: *Comparison method violates its general contract!*

I understand that this exception is typically generated when the comparison method is not properly implemented but, in my case, its implementation is fairly obvious:

```
public static class ShowdownSingleValueVO implements Comparable<ShowdownSingleValueVO>{
    int hashValue;
    byte showdownValue;
    public ShowdownSingleValueVO(int hashValue, byte showdownValue) {
        this.hashValue = hashValue;
        this.showdownValue = showdownValue;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ShowdownSingleValueVO o) {
        return this.hashValue - o.hashValue;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the objective is to have the values sorted by their hashValue attribute.

Any idea / hint on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are running into an `int` overflow. Since hash codes could be arbitrarily large in magnitude, it is conceivable that  subtraction would overflow for some pairs of values, producing a positive when subtracting two negative numbers.

Replace subtraction with the [implementation from `Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29) to fix this problem:

```
public int compareTo(ShowdownSingleValueVO o) {
    return Integer.compare(this.hashValue, o.hashValue);
}
```